# nginx: fastcgi_cache_path empty

Tags: nginx, cache, fastcgi

I wanted to try `fastcgi_cache` on my nginx 1.5.8 setup as shown [here](http://seravo.fi/2013/optimizing-web-server-performance-with-nginx-and-php).

In nginx conf, http section, I added:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m
max_size=1000m inactive=60m;
```

In server section:

```
    set $cache_uri $request_uri;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~*
"(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)")
{
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~*
"comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;


        ##
        # Fastcgi cache
        ##
        set $skip_cache 1;
                if ($cache_uri != "null cache") {
                    add_header X-Cache-Debug "$cache_uri $cookie_nocache
$arg_nocache$arg_comment $http_pragma $http_authorization";
            set $skip_cache 0;
        }
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
                   fastcgi_cache_key
$scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
            fastcgi_cache_valid any 8m;
                   fastcgi_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
                fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout
invalid_header http_500;

    }
```

I `chown`ed `/var/cache/nginx` to www-data user (and group) and `chmod`ded it to
`775`.
I restarted nginx but the folder is always empty. Is it normal? How can I
test if `fastcgi_cache` is working?

Comment: What is in your fastcgi.conf?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KBaqMFa9

Comment: Try chmoding the directory 777 and see if it works. If so, what is the user/group on the files?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set `fastcgi_cache microcache;` at some point of your configuration. The default value `null` disabled caching: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache

In order to check it, see if the `X-Cache-Debug` header is present at the response. If not, you are being too restrictive to what can be cached. Nginx also honors the `Cache-Control` header you set at the HTTP response — you can use/check it in your applications instead of adding too many conditions for caching.

Comment: I already tried but I receive an error saying that there's a double value of fastcgi_cache...

Comment: Do you receive the X-Cache-Debug header?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal.

Nowhere in your configuration do you have the [`fastcgi_cache`](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_cache) directive.

If not specified, the implied value is `off`.  If you want for any caching to go on, you'd better mention `fastcgi_cache microcache;` somewhere, where the `microcache` part is the name of your `keys_zone` from `fastcgi_cache_path`.